# Why would the creation_timestamp and last_updated_timestamp attributes differ for a mlflow.entities.model_registry.ModelVersion instance

Tags: mlflow

The documentation on `ModelVersion` at
https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.entities.html?highlight=modelversion#mlflow.entities.model_registry.ModelVersion is kind of sparse.

I do the two attributes could differ, e.g.

```
pd.Timestamp(mv.creation_timestamp, unit='ms')
Timestamp('2023-02-27 02:27:43.525000')

pd.Timestamp(mv.last_updated_timestamp, unit='ms')
Timestamp('2023-02-27 02:35:35.133000')
```

but wondering why

Comment: Could you provide sample code and share what registry backend you're using? It could depend on the backend used for your model registry service. For example, MLflow's file store implementation will use the same timestamp for both model creation/update when a new model is registered, see code [here](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/e4ac7ccf7a403fe0e4e673fd7f18df0f5df3bfe2/mlflow/store/model_registry/file_store.py#L146-L181) for lines 169 and 170 specifically. You may also be inadvertently triggering an update.

Comment: it's using postgres